# How can I apply regEx in p:column?

Tags: jsf, filter, primefaces, datatable

I have a p:datatable that contains p:column like this:

```
<p:column headerText="#{text['trip.committente']}" filterBy="#{trip.committente.name}" filterStyle="width:100%" filterMatchMode="contains" rendered="#{tripList.broker.showCustomer}" sortBy="#{trip.committente.name}">
    <h:outputText value="#{trip.committente.name}" />
</p:column>
```

I would like to apply a regEx that for example if I insert the string "spa" all the strings containing both "spa" and "s.p.a." are shown.
Therefore for the user it must not be necessary to insert the special characters and if the user enters them the inserted ones must also be ignored.

I've already tried

```
<p:keyFilter regEx="/[a-z0-9]/i" />
```

And

```
<f:validateRegex pattern="[^a-zA-Z0-9]" />
```

but they don't work.

Comment: How did you link the keyFilter or validator to your column filter intpu? What is `don't work`?

Comment: I put them inside the column tag

Comment: You'll need a custom `filterFunction` and a `<f:facet name="filter">` providing your very custom filter input component just like in the [primefaces showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml)

Comment: @Selaron: filterFunction is client-side, filtering. I get the impression op wants to use it server side for searching, but I might be wrong

Comment: @Kukeltje in the docs and showcase `<p:column filterFunction=..` is a method expression.

Comment: ok I'll try to use a custom filterFunction. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Selaron: Sorry, yes but still a filter (on the current resultset) and not searching...

Comment: @Kukeltje true, in case of LazyLoading the filter would have to be implemented within the `LazyModel.load` method.